# Many to one implementation in keras

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a many to one model where inputs are word vectors of size **d** . I need to output a vector of size **d** at the end of LSTM .

[image]

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras) , it is mentioned to use(for a many to one model)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
```

I am still doubtful about how to specify input and more importantly output dimensions in the keras model

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is actually for `one-to-many` scenario - but for the output of size 1. If you want to have an output of size `d` you need to try the following code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(d, input_shape=(len_seq, d)))
```

Moreover - with word vectors I strongly advise you to use [`Embedding`](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings) layer which is designed for your use case. Use it as an input to your `LSTM` then.

Comment: I think the code I gave is valid for many-to-one case where at each timestep input is an integer and LSTM outputs one and only one output which is at the end . so shouldn't it be many-to-one code?

Comment: @MysticForce did you come up with a solution? struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Input is a 3D tensor of shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dims)

So it will look something like this:

```
batch_input = np.empty([batch_size] + [timesteps] + [d])
```

There will be one output (the last sequence) because 'return_state=False' in keras by default.

The output shape will be:

```
(batch_size, 1)
```

Because you only have one unit in your LSTM. If you want an output with 'd' dimensions then you have to change LSTM to

```
LSTM(d, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim))
```