# How to use keras to implement second many-to-many architecture of LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have searched on google, most blog is about many-to-one or the first many-to-many architecture, is there any example for the last architecture. thx

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many to one and many to many LSTM examples in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras)

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the timestep=input_size+output_size-1,and the last (output_size-1) input is all zeros;at last layer,add a masking layer to filter the first (input_size-1) output.So we can get a input_size to output_size LSTM architecture.