# Reshaping train and test sets for LSTMs in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, forecasting

So I've seen a few SO posts and Issue posts on the Keras Github about this but none of these solutions seem to work for me so far.

My question relates to the input_shape for an LSTM in Keras. Unlike most examples my problem is a time-series forecasting problem and has nothing to do with the types of classification examples I see all over the place.

I would like to know how to reshape my training and test data sets when fitting an LSTM model in Keras. **For my use case I'd like to model an LSTM with 82 time-steps and 40 features per batch**

```
# train_X, test_X, train_y & test_y are numpy arrays
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)

> ((57482, 40), (57482,), (12546, 40), (12546,))

# For my use case I'd like to model an LSTM with 82 time-steps and 40 features per batch

# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0]/82, 82, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0]/82, 82, test_X.shape[1]))

train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0]/82, 82, 1))
test_y = test_y.reshape((test_y.shape[0]/82, 82, 1))

print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)

> ((701, 82, 40), (701, 82, 1), (153, 82, 40), (153, 82, 1))
```

When I now create and LSTM and then attempt to fit it, like so,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=1, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

I get the following error,

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_15 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (701, 82, 1)
```

I think I understand the concept of the input_shape and batch_size yet I'm clearly not able to reshape my train and test sets to match what Keras requires. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have one prediction for a set of timesteps or a prediction for every timestep?

Comment: I have a scalar target value per time-step. So in this case I have 82 targets I'd like to use for each batch of 82 x 40 training matrix

Comment: your last LSTM `retrun_sequences=True`

Comment: @djk47463 that worked! Could you explain why it did?

Comment: It is the setting for a many-to-many LSTM structure, theres a ton on posts on SO that cover this. The default  setting is `False` which is a many-to-one LSTM structure which is typical for LSTMs, but for your case the setup is a bit different.

Comment: i.e. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras)